# Dagster UI not showing on Digital Ocean with nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, digital-ocean, dagster

I'm trying to run open-source Dagster on a digital ocean droplet. This droplet is working OK for MLFlow and accessing our database via phpmyadmin.

When I try to access the Dagster UI via `www.dev.ourdomainname.co.uk/dagsterapp` I get the title "Dagit" and the console shows these errors:

`Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://www.dev.ourdomainname.co.uk/static/js/main.751d2cd1.js`

and some "Content-Security-Policy warnings".

Interestingly, pointing the browser at: `www.dev.ourdomainname.co.uk/dagsterapp/dagit_info` does show the expected version numbers.

Why does the react front end not get loaded properly? What should I be checking?

Our nginx.conf looks like this:

```
events
{
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http
{
    fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    server
    {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name dev.ourdomainname.co.uk www.dev.ourdomainname.co.uk;
        if ($host = dev.ourdomainname.co.uk)
        {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        if ($host = www.dev.ourdomainname.co.uk)
        {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    return 404;
    }
    server
    {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.ourdomainname.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.ourdomainname.co.uk/privkey.pem;
        server_name dev.ourdomainname.co.uk www.dev.ourdomainname.co.uk;
        root /;
        location /dagsterapp/ {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=5s;
            set $upstream_endpoint http://dagsterapp:3000;
            rewrite ^/dagsterapp(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
        }
        location /mlflow/ {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=5s;
            set $upstream_endpoint http://mlflow:5000;
            rewrite ^/mlflow(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
        location /phpmyadmin/ {
            client_max_body_size 50M;
            resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=5s;
            set $upstream_endpoint http://phpmyadmin:80;
            rewrite ^/phpmyadmin(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the similar issue as well where I deployed my dagster to K8S cluster fronted by Ngnix, one hacky workaround is you can rewrite /static and /graphql to the dagster app to make it work. But in the long run you might wanna create an issue in dagster repo for a quick frontend fix. I ransacked a bit of dagster doc but I didn't find the frontend base url config so good luck with ur debuggin'!  For now seems like u need 2 add `dagit -l dagsterapp`

- [[Content Gap] Document sample reverse proxy config for Dagit webserver - Dagster Issue](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/4104)

More on that note, nginx's rewrite-target will clash with dagster causing too many redirect error, so you'd need to configure the rewrite url to not use that annotation, then u'll b all gud

Comment: Thanks, this helped. We also had to put the dagster app at the root level in the nginx config.